# How to use sum case query in netbeans

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am using the query below as:

```
    String qry1 = "SELECT SUM(*) FROM class_cse where Student_ID='" + StudentUserBean.getUserId() + "'";
    try {
        ResultSet rs, rs1;
        rs = db2.stmt.executeQuery(qry1);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String count = rs.getString("SUM(*)");
            jTextField6.setText(count);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AdminInfo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

now I use this query

```
    String qry1=select sum(case when maths = 'ABSENT' then 1 else 0 end) + 
            sum(case when ca = 'ABSENT' then 1 else 0 end) + 
            sum(case when cn = 'ABSENT' then 1 else 0 end) 
     from attendance_table;
```

the sum of this query is set in jTextField5. Could you tell me how to use this query?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options. The first is getting the result by position, not by column name:

```
String sum = rs.getString(1);
```

or:

```
int sum = rs.getInt(1);
```

The second is adding an alias to the result, e.g. myresult:

```
String qry1=select sum(case when maths = 'ABSENT' then 1 else 0 end) + 
            sum(case when ca = 'ABSENT' then 1 else 0 end) + 
            sum(case when cn = 'ABSENT' then 1 else 0 end) myresult 
     from attendance_table;
```

and use it:

```
String count = rs.getString("myresult");
```

Comment: My problem is solved.. Please tell me how 'alias' works in sql.

Comment: Just you can add any name to the columns in the select clause, and then you can use those names when reading the columns.